# How to import outside class into Android auto generated BuildConfig.class

Tags: android, gradle

I have some constants in `"GlobalConstants.java"`,I config debug and release URL in `build.gradle` using `buildConfigField`, how can I import `GlobalConstants.URL`_TEST into `build.gradle`, and then auto-generated `BuildConfig` auto imports `GlobalConstants`?

Comment: anyone knows???

Comment: who can help me???